# JQuery Ajax response not working | Php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function email(){
var myTextField = document.getElementById('email_hidden').value;
//alert(myTextField);
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    data: "email_user="+myTextField,
    success: function(response){
    alert(response);    

}
});
}
</script>
```

My sendmail.php code is like this.

```
    <?php
    $to = $_REQUEST['email_user'];
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Haan Test<haan@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $message_body = "Your Details";
    $subject = "Check mail";
    mail($to, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
    echo "success";
    ?>
```

and my html looks like this.

```
   <div id="email_hide"><a href="#" onclick="email()" >Send Email</a></div>
```

I am getting the response in my firebug console as success
but i could not alert the response. I can receive the mail also for the above jquery ajax functionality(sendmail.php)

In other words, how to alert the response after ajax call..
I have tried onComplete also. plz help me with this.

My Scenerio is like this:
User page(index1.html) >> Paypal Sandbox (for transaction) >> User page(index2.html)
Here in index2.html, i fetch last transaction details from paypal sandbox with a send mail
at the top right corner, so when user clicks the send mail(anchor tag) the mail should be sent via ajax jquery call.

Thanks 
Haan

Comment: what data format is response?

Comment: can you paste the exact message data received in your firebug, after the request is complete?

Comment: @charlietfl - the response from sendmail.php is success. i have edited my code. plz check it

Comment: @linuxeasy - juz i received a success in my firebug console, and i can receive mails from the above code. sendmail.php is working fine. i want my response alert :(

Comment: firebug console? firebug console can give you javascript messages like those frmo `console.log('success')`. A right way would be to check your network tab for the url -> `sendmail.php` and see what its response is and tell us!

Comment: @linuxeasy - the scenerio is lik this. i have a page that is redirected from payment paypal sandbox along with my last transaction details. so when user clicks the send mail button after redirect from sandbox paypal, the mail should be sent via jquery ajax

Comment: I have checked your code and response 'success' is being alerted. Also i have received mail. You have done nothing wrong. I must say just make sure that you have passed <input type="hidden" name="email_hidden" id="email_hidden" value="user@mail.com" /> in your HTML.

Comment: @linuxeasy - please check my question again, i have reviewed. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the shorthand jquery method for post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function email(){
        var myTextField = document.getElementById('email_hidden').value;
        //alert(myTextField);
        $.post("sendmail.php", {"email_user": myTextField}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: please check my question again, i have reviewed. :D

Answer (score 5):

If ur datatype is json ,then try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function email(){
var myTextField = document.getElementById('email_hidden').value;
//alert(myTextField);
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    data: "email_user="+myTextField,
     dataType: "json", 
    success: function(response){
    alert(response);    

}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: please check my question again, i have reviewed. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try add

```
$.ajax({    
   type: "POST",
   url: "sendmail.php",
   data: "email_user="+myTextField,
   success: function(response){
      alert("Success\n" + response);    
   },
   error: function(errMsg) {
      alert("Error\n" + errMsg);
   }
});
```

and see which one gets called.

Comment: no change. i dnt get any alert even after adding ur code. any other suggestions plz?

Comment: @hjaffer2001  it could be possible that your code is timing out on the server side? If you want you can try modify so that echo 'success'; is before mail(); and call flush();

Actually, give it a test and comment out mail(); see what happens. Maybe just do a print_r($_POST); die(); at the beginning of the code?

Comment: the scenerio is lik this. i have a page that is redirected from payment paypal sandbox along with my last transaction details. so when user clicks the send mail button after redirect from sandbox paypal, the mail should be sent via jquery ajax

Comment: Never mind the scenario :) Have you tried out what I suggested?

Comment: This is my response to the print_r($POST);die();
Array
(
    [email_user] => haan@gmail.com
)
Now, your comments plz

Comment: hm. I'll give it a last shot.
Have you tried commenting out mail()? Have you tried putting echo 'success'; flush(); before the mail(); function? Did the alert box popup when you did print_r($_POST); die();? As I've said it could be that your script is timing out and your not getting anything back. That is my comment.

Comment: Also, another thing - it could be possible you have white-spaces at the top of your script, please make sure <?php is at the very top left of your script (and on the parent scripts if its including anything/being included). You may want to look into using ob_start(); ob_flush(); to, read up on the documentation [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)